# Limit Checkbox Selection

Tags: checkbox, statistics, limit, calculator

I have made a stats calculator on a game Miscrits
Now i want to limit the checkboxes to be selected as We can put only 3 relics on a Miscrit
So i used this Script:- http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/checkboxlimit.shtml
My stats Calculator: http://jc23.site90.com/UkjxA
when i apply that script it doesnt seem to work 
My Checkboxes are in a table .So maybe due to that it may not be working
Please Help me :)